# Caso de teste é um caso de uso?

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Tenho duvidas sobre *caso de uso* e *caso de teste*. Em meu entendimento ambos são as mesmas coisas, apenas um diagrama de UML, porem, na faculdade o meu professor disse que um *caso de teste* não é um diagrama e nem um *caso de uso*, mas não entrou em detalhes, entretanto, outas pessoas diziam que o *caso de teste* é um *caso de uso* ou seja um diagrama de UML. Agora estou confuso em relação a esses dois conceitos. O exemplo a seguir de um *caso de uso* pode ser considerado um *caso de teste*?

Exemplo do *caso de uso* que criei para ilustração:
[image: Caso de uso]

Caso não, o que seria um *caso de teste*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um caso de uso é uma descrição em alto nivel de um requisito solicitado pelo usuário. Já um caso de teste é um cenário determinado de como o sistema deve se comportar em uma sitação especifica, seja atráves de entradas ou saidas.

Ou seja ambos são artefatos diferentes que possuem finalidades diferentes e que tem algumas informações incomum.

O caso de teste pode se referir a regras de negócio(alto nível de abstração) ou verificar como determinadas estruturas internas do software se comportam(baixo nível esse tipo de informação não está especificada no caso de uso).

Talvez a confusão seja que um regra de negócio pode virar um caso de teste.

Comment: Tem alguma informação errada na resposta? posso corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Caso de uso se trata de um documento que contem os requisitos do sistema.

Caso de teste é basicamente descreve os passos e resultados esperados para cada ação.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de um caso de uso é possível derivar um ou mais casos de teste.

O caso de uso é como um artefato que representa o que o desenvolvedor deve implementar sobre o requisito.

Nessa associação, o caso de teste representaria o que o usuário deve poder executar, dado um requisito.