# Casos de uso Conceito e casos de uso Processo

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml, casos-de-uso

Em engenharia de software temos os famosos casos de uso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um trabalho de faculdade me deparo com o seguinte:

UCC - Casos de uso de conceito
UCP - Casos de uso de processo
UCR - Casos de uso de Relátorio

UCR - seria os casos de uso relacionado a emissão de relatórios.

Mas o UCC e o UCP??

Qual a finalidade de fazer essa separação de casos de uso?

Não seria tudo a mesma coisa?

Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nada sobre essas siglas, tudo me leva
ao caso de uso normal.

Comment: Aqui tem uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107404/caso-de-teste-%C3%A9-um-caso-de-uso) relacionada.

Comment: UCP me remete a "use case point". UCC nunca vi... "Caso de uso complexo", talvez? Ambos estariam, pra mim, relacionados com contagem de pontos por função e não com modelagem de software. Tem alguma referência pra gente que contextualize estas siglas?

Comment: @Caffé, tenho um trabalho onde é pedido casos de uso de conceito e casos de uso de processos, dei uma vasta procurada pela web e também não achei nada.. isso seria de engenharia de software. No fim acho que é tudo a mesma coisa..

Comment: alguns links: http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/use-case http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5150/2014fa/slides/D2-use-cases.pdf

Comment: Interessante, vou até procurar saber pois sempre vi os casos de uso de uma maneira generalizada, sem essas subdivisões.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Resposta Curta:**
A dificuldade em encontrar material sobre o assunto é porque não existe mesmo essa diferenciação na literatura.

**Resposta Longa**
Editado com a edição da pergunta.

Realmente tudo isso é caso de uso.
Mas nesse exercício, eles estão logicamente divididos no seu projeto, agrupando os casos de uso por tipos.

Por exemplo, uma interpretação possível desta separação:

Os casos de uso conceito, são os que não existem na prática, eles existem apenas no pensamento. Neste caso, tem dois que se aplicariam. Por exemplo, procurar registro do paciente facilita outros dois casos de uso, mas na prática, ele não é um caso de uso que algum ator inicia. Na prática ele está dentro de outros dois casos de uso e a separação apenas simplifica a modelagem.

Já os casos de uso de processo, seriam aqueles que facilitam ou padronizam um processo. Por exemplo, marcar ou cancelar consulta. Este tipo de caso de uso pode gerar dados para os casos de uso de relatório.

E os casos de uso de relatório, seriam os casos de uso que geram o relatório em si. Por exemplo, o caso de uso "Consultar Agenda", permitiria a um médico ver um relatório baseado no processo de marcar e cancelar consultas.

Comment: Boa abordagem! Eu só diferenciaria Conceito de Processo da seguinte forma: A) Processo: tudo que envolve operação da clínica. B) Conceito: tudo o que não envolve operação, mas que é aplicado como conceito dentro da operação. Neste caso, UCC então seria o médico Pedir (receitar) Remédio.